# Spark 1.6 - Association Rules algorithm - Cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]])

Tags: scala, apache-spark, data-mining, apache-spark-mllib

I've this code to find some association rules:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.AssociationRules
import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowth.FreqItemset

val data = sc.textFile("FILE");

val transactions: RDD[Array[String]] = data.map(s => s.trim.split(','));

val ar = new AssociationRules()
  .setMinConfidence(0.8)
val results = ar.run(transactions)

results.collect().foreach { rule =>
  println("[" + rule.antecedent.mkString(",")
    + "=>"
    + rule.consequent.mkString(",") + "]," + rule.confidence)
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
<console>:50: error: overloaded method value run with alternatives:
  [Item](freqItemsets: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowth.FreqItemset[Item]])org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.AssociationRules.Rule[Item]] <and>
  [Item](freqItemsets: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowth.FreqItemset[Item]])(implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[Item])org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.AssociationRules.Rule[Item]]
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]])
         val results = ar.run(transactions)
```

How can I transform this rdd to the type that the association rules needs?

Many thanks!

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, then you should mark it as the correct answer. It motivates the answer givers and helps those who are reading the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will first have to create an FPGrowthModel and then pass the freqItemsets like below:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.AssociationRules
import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowth.FreqItemset
import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowth

val data = sc.textFile("FILE");

val transactions: RDD[Array[String]] = data.map(s => s.trim.split(','));

val fpg = new FPGrowth()
  .setMinSupport(0.2)
  .setNumPartitions(10)

val model = fpg.run(transactions) // creates the FPGrowthModel

val ar = new AssociationRules()
  .setMinConfidence(0.8)

val results = ar.run(model.freqItemsets)
```